# Why does play/pause shortcut not work?

Tags: 11.10, unity, sound, shortcut-keys

When I would like to **pause/play** my radiotray application used the required **shortcut** the next window can been seen:

[image: not expected window]

How can I solve this problem? Sometimes the shortcut works, but I do not know why.

Comment: I think this is a bug in Ubuntu 11.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/860600 :(

Answer (score 1):

Your media keys are likely working fine. However, they control your default music player which—judging by the overlay—isn't launched, or has nothing in the playlist.

[image]

RadioTray can't be added as the default music player, unfortunately, because it doesn't support the MPRIS API Ubuntu uses for extra-application media controls. [The status of that issue can be tracked here, it seems.](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/radiotray/ticket/78)

Comment: I think no this is the problem. My default 'Music' is VLC, but it can not be play/pause with default shortcut. Moreover sometimes the shortcut works (I has written already this in the question description :) ).

Comment: @Regisz Try opening VLC with a few songs and use the keys.

Comment: hm, very interesting: If I start Banshee, then I can use default shortcut-key to play/pause the RadioTray application :). But if I start a media in Banshee then the shortcut-key manages both application.

Comment: I tried your idea, but VLC did not respond.

Answer (score 1):

@Regisz: Same here, I have Audacious as my default media player, but it doesn't work with multimedia buttons on my wireless keyboard or any keys on my headset. As soon as I start Rhytmbox while having Audacious still running, I can "control" both media players with a single Play/Pause button somehow.

Anyway, this question could be a duplicate of:
[Can I map the media player function keys to a media player other than Totem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131648/can-i-map-the-media-player-function-keys-to-a-media-player-other-than-totem)

BTW, I've just found out that the new version of Audacious has own plugin for multimedia keys, so my similar issue has been resolved with it. Now it works!

Comment: +1 for referring to the duplicate thread