# Can I map the media player function keys to a media player other than Totem?

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc

I can use my function key+stop, next, previous, etc to control totem using my Keyboard. Can I map these settings entirely to vlc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you want to enable media controls for VLC in Ubuntu 10.10 ...

*(I can't speak for other releases, anyone?)*

... you will need to unset the media control keyboard global shortcuts in order to use them with VLC.

1) Open Keyboard shortcuts settings. Disable media play/pause/skip/reverse and whatever else you wish to use with VLC. To disable a shortcut, you have to press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> while in "changing shortcut"-mode.

[image]

2) Open VLC preferences and set shortcuts for the keys you want to use. Tools>preferences>Hotkeys tab. Change "Global" setting: Double-click "global" list item area: hit according media key. hit "apply", "save".

[image]

3) Restart VLC.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 12.04 too.  The only way I found to 'disable' the key in step 1 was to assign the same key to everything, then it would set the previously assigned key to 'Disabled'.  Is there another way ?

Comment: @olafure To disable a key you have to press <Backspace>, while in the 'changing shortcut'-mode. I've found it in the help for Keyboard settings (press <F1> while in the Settings->Keyboard).

Comment: It works fine for ubuntu 18.04. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem of setting this by pressing keys. The system does not grab a combination of fn+any key. If this is the case, just edit `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`

add the following lines at the beginning of the file:

```
global-key-play-pause=Media Play Pause
global-key-next=Media Next Track
global-key-prev=Media Prev Track
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is answered on launchpad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+question/109827

Comment: I don't think that has the answer.